# What is an alternative to ifelse() in R?

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I have a variable (say, `VarX`) with values 1:4 in a dataset with approximately 2000 rows. There are other variables in the dataset too. I would like to create a new variable (`NewVar`) so that if the value `VarX` is `1`, the value of `NewVar` is `0.32` (the value from `myMat[1, 1]`), if the value `VarX` is `2`, the value of `NewVar` is `0.05` (the value from `myMat[2, 1]`) and so on...

```
myMat
      VarA VarB VarC
[1,] 0.32  0.34 0.27
[2,] 0.05  0.02 0.11
[3,] 0.11  0.11 0.17
[4,] 0.52  0.52 0.45
```

I have tried the following and it works fine:

```
df$NewVar <-    ifelse(df$VarX == 1, 0.32, 
                       ifelse(df$VarX == 2, 0.05,
                              ifelse(df$VarX == 3, 0.11,
                                     ifelse(df$VarX == 4, 0.52, 0))))
```

However, I have another variable (say, `VarY`) which has 182 values and another matrix with 182 different values. So, using `ifelse()` would be quite tedious. Is there another way to perform the task in R? Thank you!

Comment: Am I missing something, or could you just do `NewVar <- myMat[[VarY,1]]`

Comment: I tried what you suggested but it only returns the very last value (`0.52`) for every value of `VarX`.

Comment: I sincerely doubt that, because that makes no sense. Can you please post the complete code you integrated that into.

Comment: `df$NewVar <- myMat[[VarX, 1]]`. It says `VarX` not found. When I try `VarX <- df$VarX` and   `df$NewVar <- myMat[[VarX, 1]]`, I get the error saying `: attempt to select more than one element`.

Comment: I also tried: `df$NewVar <- NULL

VarX <- df$VarX
for (VarX in 1:4) {
 df$NewVar <- myMat[VarX, 1]]
}' . Again, it only returns the last value (`0.52`) from the matrix.

Comment: Something like this should work (slight tweak on previous comment) `df$NewVar <- 0; df$NewVar[df$VarX %in% 1:4] <- myMat[df$varX[df$VarX %in% 1:4], 1]`.

Comment: It did. Thank you very much!